# How to close info window batchly

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

This habit was inherited from windows 7. I normally choose all the files and then right click and get the folder size. But when I do this in Macos, mac open all the file info. Then how can I close those windows at once? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To close all **Finder** *windows* at once, press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while clicking the **File** menu in **Finder** and select **Close All** or just press <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.

By the way, to get **Summary Info** for multiple *files/folders* in **Finder**, select the target *files/folders* and then <kbd>Control</kbd> click and select **Get Summary Info**.  Then you only have one **Get Info** *sheet* open and you can press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to close it.

To close just the ones from **Get Info** [use this AppleScript](https://gist.github.com/jamesstout/5990388), by [James Stout](https://gist.github.com/jamesstout).

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindowList to windows (* get all Finder windows *)
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindowList (* loop through them *)
        set shouldClose to false (* reset to false *)
        set this_item to item i of theWindowList (* get a window from the list *)
        set windowName to name of this_item (* get the window'ss name  *)
        (* this list should contain class property that tells you the type of window - which is nice *)
        (* Class would be either "Finder window" for normal windows or "information window" for the Info windows *)
        (* However, it doesn't contain the class property. alas. *)
        (* So to differentiate, we can use the current view/panel props *)
        set thePropList to get properties of this_item
        (* in a try/catch as prop not set for the diff windows *)
        try
            set CurrentView to current panel of thePropList
            set shouldClose to true (* no error, it's an info panel, so close *)
        on error
            log "Not an info panel, leaving open: " & windowName
        end try
        (* this try/catch is just for a double check, feel free to comment out *)
        try
            set CurrentView to current view of thePropList
        on error
            if shouldClose = false then log "Not an info panel: " & windowName
        end try
        if windowName ends with " Info" and shouldClose then
            close this_item
            log "Closing info panel: " & windowName
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I use the terminal to kill all of the info windows? Since I can't find the process with the name including "*info"